# one-hot-encode validation data

Tags: python, pandas, one-hot-encoding

I have a one-hot-encoded feature matrix where features are the substrings of the training data.

I just have this final dataframe which contains `rows = samples, columns = substrings (one-hot-encoded)`.
Now I want to one-hot-encode a new set of data.
The data consists of `rows = samples, columns = String` and I need to check if the string of each sample contains any of the substrings(features) and one-hot-encode them.

Looping through all strings and substrings won't be fast enough, as I have quite an amount of data.
What would be a fast way to solve this?

EDIT:
Example:
I have some strings in a list and have a one hot encoded matrix with substrings of those:

```
strings = ['foobarista', 'foobar']

substrings = {'foo' : [1,1] ,
       'bar' : [1,1],
       'ist' : [0,1],
       'sta' : [0,1]}

df_one_hot = pd.DataFrame(substrings)
```

Let's say this is my training data, so I have the features `foo, bar, ist, sta`.

Now I have new data:

```
new_strings = ['barista', 'barfoo', 'house']
```

And want to check those new strings, if they contain any of the substrings from the dataframe above.

```
new_substrings = {'foo' : [0,1,0] ,
       'bar' : [1,1,0],
       'ist' : [1,0,0],
       'sta' : [1,0,0]}


new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_substrings)
```

Comment: Can you post an example of your data, ideally as a piece of code that one can run in python? Further how would you like your output to look like, also show it as a table, rather than explaining it in text.

Comment: I edited the post and added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting to the `new_substrings` can be done by a double list-comprehension. The inner comprehension goes through all entries in `new_string`, and the outer creates a dictionary for all `sub_strings`:

```
import re

new_strings = ['barista', 'barfoo', 'house']
sub_strings = ['foo', 'bar', 'ist', 'sta']
new_substrings= {sub_s: [ (re.search(sub_s, s) is not None)*1 for s in new_strings] for sub_s in sub_strings}
print(new_substrings)
```

This returns:

```
{'foo': [0, 1, 0], 'bar': [1, 1, 0], 'ist': [1, 0, 0], 'sta': [1, 0, 0]}
```

You can then create your dataframe with `df = pd.DataFrame(new_substrings)`.